# Android SFTP preview client?

Tags: android, sftp

Are there any client softwares for Android phones that can show a preview picture from an SFTP place?

Ex.: regular local photo apps can show previews, but are there any for SFTP?

Many-many thanks.

Comment: Some [file explorers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156) (link goes to my website) offer that. Not sure which one exactly to recommend, long time didn't use any.

Comment: Note that there's no way to retrieve a preview picture with SFTP. So if any client can actually show the preview images, it will have to download full images for that anyway.